# login session expired while running automation script

Tags: java, selenium, oop, webdriver, testng

I'm trying to run automation script of ecommerce demo application.
But while adding item into cart, item will added into cart but login session expired.
I developed script using selenium, testNG tool and java programming language.

```
public void selectItems() {
        webDriverCommonUtil1.waitForPageToLoad();
        webDriverCommonUtil1.scrolling();
        /*
         * try { Thread.sleep(4000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
         */

        sheetName = "Item Details";
        product_TestData = FileLib.getTestData(sheetName, count, 0);
        WebElement item = BaseClass.dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + product_TestData + "']"));
        webDriverCommonUtil1.waitForElementPresent(item);
        webDriverCommonUtil1.clickElementWithJavascript(item);  // item.click();
        count++;
        System.out.println("item clicked");
        
        webDriverCommonUtil1.waitForElementPresent(addToCartBtn);
        addToCartBtn.click();
        System.out.println("cart clicked");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        webDriverCommonUtil1.acceptAlertMessage();
        System.out.println("Alert accepted");
        
        webDriverCommonUtil1.waitForElementPresent(homeMenu);
        homeMenu.click();
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting? and at what step?

Comment: Does the error occure when you add item to cart manualy? If yes it's problem of the page itself.

Comment: Problem is not about coding, it's about process, means while adding 1'st item or sometimes 2'nd item into cart login sessions got expired and there's no specific error about that. because i debug code and on just after below line executed ==> webDriverCommonUtil1.clickElementWithJavascript(item);  login session expired and script get executed e.g. add 2'nd and 3'rd item into cart without login. Nandan A

Comment: Error is not occured while adding items to cart manually, only while running script. pburgr

Comment: Issue resolved thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most of the oauth 2.0 applications having max of 1hr session time and payment applications having 15mins of maximum session time. always we should remember following things,

1. Our whole testcase execution time should not be exceed 1hr - max 2hr,
2. Include login and logout in the each test - this will prevent the session expire.
3. If we have bunch of testcases running for couple of hour, split them into pieces. like limit the execution of testcases. 50 by 50.